Detail view not fitting its container when hiding/showing sidebar in NavigationSplitView
I have something like this:
NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $fetcher.columnVisibility) {
    SideBar()
} detail: {
    Content()
    .onAppear {
        if isVision {
            fetcher.columnVisibility = .all
        }
    }
    .onDisappear {
        if isVision {
            fetcher.columnVisibility = .detailOnly
        }
     }
}

Content() includes a NavigationStack showing some horizontal scrolls on its root. When going into a detail, I'm hiding the main SideBar() and showing again when going back. It works well but I just noticed that when showing it again, the SideBar() cannot fully scroll horizontally anymore as if the Content() width is not correctly calculated, which looks like a bug to me. But I was wondering if there's a better place to show / hide the SideBar() to avoid it.
Any idea to fix / improve it?
